# Magento same product in cart with different prices

Tags: magento-1.9

I have 5 items in cart with same product id.

I want to set first 4 item price as 9.99 and 5th item onwards will have of 20% discount on original price.

I have set first 4 items as club_item and 5th product onwards as other product(using my custom table).

If I add only 4 items, then all the 4 product's price is showing correctly as 9.99;

But when I add all 5 items, then all the 5 items price is changing and it is the price of last item added. Means all items are showing price = (actual_productprice - 20% discount).

How can I show different price for only 5th Item.

I have below event

```
    <events>            
           <sales_quote_add_item>
               <observers>
                  <Company_Module_Model_Observer>
                     <type>singleton</type>
                     <class>Company_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                     <method>updatePrice</method>
                  </Company_Module_Model_Observer>
              </observers>
           </sales_quote_add_item>   
    </events>
```

And my observer function is :-

```
    public function updatePrice($observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();
        $quote_item = $event->getQuoteItem();

        $productId = $quote_item->getProductId();

        if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
             $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
              $customer_id = $customerData->getId();
        }

        $_customModel = Mage::getModel('custom/custom')->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', array('eq'=>$productId))
                ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', array('eq'=>$customer_id));

        $_customData = $_customModel->getData();

        $actualPrice = $quote_item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice();

        /* this is for separating each line item in cart */
        $quote_item->addOption(array(
              "code" => "random",
              "value" => serialize(array(time()))
        ));

        $new_price = 0; 
        foreach ($_customData as $_customDataValue) {
            $_isClubProductId   = $_customDataValue['product_id'];
            $_isClubItem        = $_customDataValue['is_club_item'];

            /* Here I am differentiting the products with variable $_isClubItem */

            if($productId == $_isClubProductId && $_isClubItem == 1){
                $customPrice = 9.99;
                $new_price = round($customPrice, 4);
            }else{
                $new_price = (float)number_format($actualPrice * ((100-20) / 100),2);
            }
        }

        $quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($new_price);

        //$quote_item->save();
        $quote_item->getQuote()->save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with a shopping cart price rule. You can set the Requirements as minimum quantity in cart of 4, and apply a 20% discount on the products. The price rule will be only applied on the fifth product, and onwards.

Comment: Actually I am creating cart programatically.